# How will xml modularisation in scala 2.11 play with xml literals?

Tags: xml, scala, scala-2.11

Reading the release notes for Scala 2.11.0-RC1, I noticed that the splitting-off of scala xml to a separate jar is starting with the 2.11 series. Will this affect the use of xml literals, in 2.11 or down the line? Clearly, if you use xml literals you will also need the scala xml jar -- I'm wondering if there are plans to deprecate xml literals as well.

As an aside, I get the sense that Scala's support for XML is felt to be a mistake. As a language user, I've certainly been very happy with the support for literals and interpolation. I've found `MetaData` and `UnprefixedAttribute` to be somewhat awkward for manipulating attributes, but not terrible. What are the main issues with scala xml?

Comment: +1 to this, I'm a huge fan of XML literals, incredibly useful for generating typesafe XHTML markup, for example. I think the issue is that anti-xml and other 3rd party libs have been more or less abandoned, and Scala's built-in XML support needs work, which, if you look at one of Adriaan Moors comments in Scala 2.11 branch, is not going to come from Typesafe (they're looking for someone to create a 3rd party XML lib rather than deal with legacy warts of existing Scala XML)

Comment: The second question is a many-duplicated thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569172/state-of-xml-support-in-scala-2-9-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was [a thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.debate/12950) in which Adriaan Moors replied to @virtualeyes that xml literal syntax

> is, and has been for a while now, "effectively" deprecated.

There is [a GSOC project](http://www.scala-lang.org/gsoc/2014.html#generic_xml_interpolator) to start a macrotized interpolator for XML as first step to spinning off and divesting XML support.  The interpolator is expected to support pluggable libraries.

An XML interpolator was envisioned in the interpolation SIP, together with quasiquoting, so this has been in the works.